# Replace USB keyboard key press through a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, keyboard-events

I need to replace a key press from a USB keyboard. As a first, I am just trying to print the scan code of the pressed key. However, my current implementation prints Scan Code `7e` for every key press or even mouse movements. I used IRQ 19, which corresponds to my USB keyboard. I don't see any resources regarding USB keyboard interception. I would appreciate any pointers to get the below code to work.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/irqdesc.h>

#define KBD_IRQ             19       /* IRQ number for keyboard (i8042) */
#define KBD_DATA_REG        0x60    /* I/O port for keyboard data */
#define KBD_SCANCODE_MASK   0x7f
#define KBD_STATUS_MASK     0x80

static irqreturn_t kbd2_isr(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    char scancode;
    scancode = inb(KBD_DATA_REG);
    printk("Scan Code %x %s\n",
            scancode & KBD_SCANCODE_MASK,
            scancode & KBD_STATUS_MASK ? "Released" : "Pressed");
    return IRQ_HANDLED;

}

static int __init kbd2_init(void)
{   
    
    int retval_irqreg;
    retval_irqreg= request_irq(KBD_IRQ, (irq_handler_t) kbd2_isr, IRQF_SHARED, "kbd2", (void *)kbd2_isr);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit kbd2_exit(void)
{   printk(KERN_INFO "removed interceptKBD module \n");
    free_irq(KBD_IRQ, (void *)kbd2_isr);
}

module_init(kbd2_init);
module_exit(kbd2_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: USB keyboard is a HID device, what are you doing with your code?! Find a check how `hid-replay` works,

Comment: Thanks, @0andriy. I looked at `hid-replay`. It creates a virtual device with the help of `uhid` module and replays the keystrokes. However, I still couldn't find a way to modify the original keystrokes. `hid-replay` uses values from `hid-recorder`, which reads raw values from the device.

Comment: Good, now you know what to modify (i.e. the USB HID driver) or write your own with whatever hooks you want to have there.